# vectorizing functions to operate on NetworkX graphs

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I have a DiGraph of order n. I also have a (n x n) numpy array. I want to apply a function over the numpy array. This function is a NetworkX-based function. A small example is given below:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
eList = [('1','2'), ('1', '4'), ('2','3'), ('3','1'), ('4', '5'), ('5', '4')]
G.add_edges_from(eList)

myMatrix = np.zeros((5, 5))

def myFunc(i, j, G):
    s = np.min(G.in_degree(str(i)), G.in_degree(str(j)))/np.max(G.in_degree(str(i)), G.in_degree(str(j)))
    return s
```

Now, how do I apply 'myFunc' over all cells of 'myMatrix' ? I am not sure how to do it.

```
fv = np.vectorize(myFunc)
```

then...not sure how to call it. Currently, I am doing it in a rather clumsy way:

```
for (i, j), value in np.ndenumerate(myMatrix):
    s = np.min(G.in_degree(str(i)), G.in_degree(str(j)))/np.max(G.in_degree(str(i)), G.in_degree(str(j)))
    myMatrix[i, j] = s
    return myMatrix
```

I fear that looping over large matrices is bad and hence want to try out vectorization.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `G = nx.DiGraph()` instead? Also, `G.in_degree(0)` throws error : `NetworkXError: nbunch is not a node or a sequence of nodes.`. If it matters, I am on networkx version : `1.10`.

Comment: Correct. Changed to DiGraph(). The parameter must be a either a list of nodes or a single node name as string. Not an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use numpy.fromfunction like this

```
from __future__ import division
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

G = nx.DiGraph([('1','2'), ('1', '4'), ('2','3'), ('3','1'), ('4', '5'), ('5', '4')])
d = dict(G.in_degree())
n = len(d)

def myfunc(i,j):
    di = d[str(i+1)]
    dj = d[str(j+1)]
    return min(di,dj)/max(di,dj)

f = np.vectorize(myfunc)
a = np.fromfunction(f, (n,n), dtype=int)
print a

[[ 1.   1.   1.   0.5  1. ]
 [ 1.   1.   1.   0.5  1. ]
 [ 1.   1.   1.   0.5  1. ]
 [ 0.5  0.5  0.5  1.   0.5]
 [ 1.   1.   1.   0.5  1. ]]
```

Comment: Thanks Aric. Can one provide more arguments to the function 'myfunc' and somehow call it with the extra args in 'fromfunction'?